# How to replace characters from jobname?

Tags: pdftex, strings, xstring, jobname

I have a `tex` file with name `Chap-Name_of_Section.tex` and I running `pdflatex` on it. I want to set the title of my document automatically according to the file name. This could be done using `\jobname`.

Here is my MWE. Save this file as `Chap-Name_of_Section.tex`,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{a4wide}

\title{\textbf{\jobname}}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
The name of the tex file is {\tt{Chap-Name\_of\_Section.tex}}. I am running {\verb|pdflatex|} on the tex file. After using {\verb|\jobname|} I get the title.

I want to print the title as ``Chap: Name of Section''. Note that `-' sign is to be replaced by `:' followed by a single space and underscores (`\_') are to be replaced by spaces.
\end{document}
```

But This is not what I want. I want to print the title as `Chap: Name of Section`. Note that `-` sign is to be replaced by `:` followed by a single space and underscores `_` are to be replaced by spaces.

I have found `\StrSubstitute` from the `xstring` package. But this can change only one character. For example, if I replace `\jobname` with `\StrSubstitute[0]{\jobname}{-}{: }` in my code, the title would be, `Chap: Name_of_Section`.

How to replace both `-` and `_` accordingly ?

Comment: The package `a4wide` has been deprecated for several years. Don't use it, as it's incompatible with much more useful packages.

Comment: unrelated comment: you shouldn't be using `{\tt{..}}` (`\tt` doesn't even take an argument so `{\tt ..}` if anything) but rather `\texttt{..}`.

Comment: also the braces around the `\verb|..|` are not necessary (but don't do harm I guess)

Comment: @egreg is there something similar to `a4wide`?

Comment: @ddas Use `geometry`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from `expl3`, you can also use `StrSubstitute` with the option to save the result in a macro. Note that you need to convert `_` to the right catcode, for example using `\string`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\title{\textbf{\subfinal}}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\StrSubstitute{\jobname}{-}{: }[\subsemi]
\StrSubstitute{\subsemi}{\string_}{ }[\subfinal]
\maketitle
The name of the tex file is {\tt{Chap-Name\_of\_Section.tex}}. I am running {\verb|pdflatex|} on the tex file. After using {\verb|\jobname|} I get the title.

I want to print the title as ``Chap: Name of Section''. Note that `-' sign is to be replaced by `:' followed by a single space and underscores (`\_') are to be replaced by spaces.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: you should replace `{\tt{...}}` by `\texttt{...}`

Answer (score 4):

Same idea as in @jakun's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394496/4686), but implemented (without packages, also) in a way which is easier (more convenient, rather, as it takes less space) to extend to more special characters. Expandable, too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\long\def\DoThis #1#2\OrThat #3{\fi #1}
\makeatletter
\let\OrThat\@firstofone
\makeatother

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`_=12 % other
% if using Babel with a language that makes : a shorthand (French, e.g.)
% then you need  \catcode`: \active here and \DoThis{\noexpand: }
  \def\myParser#1{%
     \ifx\relax#1\DoThis{\@gobble}\fi
     \ifx -#1\DoThis{: }\fi
     \ifx _#1\DoThis{ }\fi
     \OrThat{#1}\myParser
  }%
  \xdef\parsedJobname{\expandafter\myParser\jobname\relax}
\endgroup

\title{\parsedJobname}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    The parsed jobname is ``\parsedJobname''.
\end{document}
```

If the above is file `Test_Titre-Un.tex` then the result is

[image]

Code for French as per code comment.

```
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`_=12 % other
  \catcode`\: \active 
  \def\myParser#1{%
     \ifx\relax#1\DoThis{\@gobble}\fi
     \ifx -#1\DoThis{\noexpand: }\fi
     \ifx _#1\DoThis{ }\fi
     \OrThat{#1}\myParser
  }%
  \xdef\parsedJobname{\expandafter\myParser\jobname\relax}
\endgroup
```

Produces (using `babel+french`):

[image]

Comment: this will not work with filenames containing spaces, but I never use such filenames to start with, and particularly with TeX. Off the top of my head I don't even recall if such filenames are authorized with TeX.

Comment: `pdflatex "I like spaces .tex"`  will work with web2c based texs using `"` to quote any spaces.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, I never tested that; will it work flawlessly in integrated environments? I guess they take care that quotes do not get lost when calling executables on auxiliary files.

Comment: @ddas do you want a solution allowing spaces in filenames? I have the impression the motivation is rather to avoid them, but in case you do want, then the answer can be amended... (it would get more complicated, though...)

Answer (score 4):

Here is more simple, format independent, expandable solution:

```
\def\cnvjobname{\expandafter\cnvjobnameA\jobname\relax}
\def\cnvjobnameA#1{\ifx\relax#1\else
   \ifx-#1: \else \expandafter\ifx\string_#1 \else #1\fi\fi
   \expandafter\cnvjobnameA\fi
}

%test:
\message{... "\cnvjobname"}

\bye
```

Answer (score 3):

Without any packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`_=12 % other
\newcommand{\myParser}[1]{%
    \let\do=\myParser
    \ifx \relax #1%
        \let\do=\relax
    \else\ifx -#1%
        : %
    \else\ifx _#1%
        \ %
    \else
        #1%
    \fi\fi\fi
    \do
}
\catcode`_=8 % subscript

\title{\expandafter\myParser\jobname\relax}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Please note that this is *not* expandable (you can not use it in an `\edef`).

This is an expandable version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \catcode`_=12 % other

    \gdef\myParser#1{%
        \ifx -#1%
            \expandafter \@firstoftwo
        \else
            \expandafter \@secondoftwo
        \fi
            {: \myParser}
            {%
                \ifx _#1%
                    \expandafter \@firstoftwo
                \else
                    \expandafter \@secondoftwo
                \fi
                    { \myParser}
                    {%
                        \ifx \relax #1%
                            \expandafter \@firstoftwo
                        \else
                            \expandafter \@secondoftwo
                        \fi
                            {}
                            {#1\myParser}%
                    }%
            }%
    }
\endgroup

\edef\parsedJobname{\expandafter\myParser\jobname\relax}
\title{\parsedJobname}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    The parsed jobname is ``\parsedJobname''.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `expl3`'s excellent regex module:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:NV \l_tmpa_tl \c_sys_jobname_str
\regex_replace_once:nnN { - } { \cO:\  } \l_tmpa_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { _ } { \  } \l_tmpa_tl
\exp_args:NV \title \l_tmpa_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\jobname` is available as `\c_sys_jobname_str`; the first instruction should be `\tl_set:NV \l_tmpa_tl \c_sys_jobname_str` and the last one `\exp_args:NV \title \l_tmpa_tl`; to be picky, the replacement string for the hyphen should be `\cO:\ `, because `:` is a letter under `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Answer (score 2):

An expandable version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\massagedjobname}{%
  \expandafter\massage@jobname\jobname\@nil
}
\newcommand{\massage@jobname}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\@nil
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\massage@token#1}%
}
\def\massage@token#1{%
  \ifx#1-%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {: \massage@jobname}%
  {\massage@token@i#1}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`?=`_
\lowercase{%
  \endgroup
  \gdef\massage@token@i#1{%
    \ifx#1?%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    { }{#1}%
    \massage@jobname
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{\massagedjobname}
\author{Me}

\maketitle

\edef\test{\massagedjobname}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\texttt{macro:->Chap: Name of Section}% check!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course there's an `expl3` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\massagedjobname}{}
 {
  \str_map_function:NN \c_sys_jobname_str \ddas_jobname:n
 }
\cs_new:Nn \ddas_jobname:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    { - }{ :~ }
    { _ }{ ~ }
   }
   { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\title{\massagedjobname}
\author{Me}

\maketitle

\edef\test{\massagedjobname}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\texttt{macro:->Chap: Name of Section}% check!
\end{document}
```