# tikzsetnextfilename - filename with spaces

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there any way to use tikzsetnextfilename for filenames with spaces?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18,prefix=external/]

\begin{document}

\tikzsetnextfilename{Filename with space}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
    \draw (2,2) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above program is just a simple example. In actual case, I have a large number of plots in my latex document. I would like to externalize the plots by setting their filenames as figure titles. Since the titles can have spaces in them, is it possible to use \tikzsetnextfilename for filenames with spaces, or is there any other way?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394489/how-to-replace-characters-from-jobname (in short: use underscores in your filenames and replace them by spaces when you want to display the filename in the document).