# \tikzsetnextfilename externalize with filename as variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, strings, variable

I want to externalize my pictures with the `external` tikzlibrary.
The problem is that there are pictures created inside `\newcommand` and i have to automatically set the filename tor the externalization.

Currently I got this to work:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=TikZfigures-]

\newcommand{\Test}[1]{
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (0,0) node (n) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \Test{Works}
    \Test{Works}
    \Test{Does not work}
\end{document}
```

When it tries to create the file "TikZfigures-Does not work.tex" the externalization doesn't do it right and crashes.
How can I avoid this problem?

I found a similar problem in this question: [TIKZ Externalize with filename and path variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416640/201657)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself after being pointed to this similar question with an excellent answer by [Marijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn):

[How to replace characters from jobname?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394495/201657)

My adapted code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=TikZfigures-]

\newcommand{\Test}[1]{
    \def\fn{#1}
    \StrSubstitute{\fn}{ }{_}[\fn]
    \tikzsetnextfilename{\fn}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (0,0) node (n) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \Test{Works}
    \Test{Works}
    \Test{Does still work}
\end{document}
```

Using `xstring` to replace the spaces with underscores makes the filename possible to be used by `externalize`.
If you have any other symbols that can't be in the filename, just replace them, too.

A problem still exists if you try

```
\begin{document}
    \Test{the same}
    \Test{the\textunderscore same}
\end{document}
```

Because it results in the same filename.
Each command on its own works, but not together.